# Website to show/monitor home network traffic?

Tags: networking

Is there any website that can show/monitor home network traffic?   E.g. what are the devices online and how much bandwidth they're using etc.

I don't want to install app on any device, is there a website, after just open it, it can scan and show these info?

Comment: The traffic has to pass through the monitoring site. Therefore, the monitoring site ***MUST*** be inside the home network. once you accept that, @IvanIvan has a good answer.  Welcome ot the site :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yup - you want `ntop` - https://www.ntop.org/

Install it on a machine that traffic passes through (I use a Pi as a router for part of my network) and you can access the GUI for reports, etc. via browser.

Comment: OP says "`I don't want to install app on any device`", BUT, OP doesn't understand what (s)he is asking :-) God answer.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** scan your home network by just visiting a website. (Thank [insert deity of choice]!)

However if you are willing to do install some software you can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for free. To monitor the traffic on your entire home network and not just the traffic that passes through your current PC, you need to use one of the methods described on this page: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet#Capture_using_a_monitor_mode_of_the_switch